# Uncheck a RadioBox angularJS

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angular-material, radio-group

I am using angularJS and Mat-Design for angularJS.

I have a big form with a md-radio-group like this

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VVVLVe

I use radio because I want to select 1 field MAXIMUM but also NO FIELD is possible.

But, If I select something, It's impossible to unselect the value even tho I set the model to null.

```
  $scope.clickStatus = function(val){
    console.log(val, $scope.data.group1)
    if(val === $scope.data.group1){
      $scope.data.group1 = null
    }
  }
```

the checkbox keep being set and the index and value are still set.

How can i uncheck that radio box ?

Comment: Please have a look at `md-checkbox` that are available in material design, they are more suitable for your requirement. For reference, check [this](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in comments, I would suggest using `md-checkbox` instead. You can uncheck all other checkboxes in the method you tie to `ng-click`